# how to vlookup beetwen two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My example;

| Code | Volume | Trade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ApplA | 500 | 1000 |
| Amazon | 1000 | 500 |
| Facebook | 250 | 750 |
| ApplE | 100 | 1500 |

```
df_samecompanies['Codes'] 

df['Volume Order'] = df['Volume'].rank(ascending=False)
df['Trade Order']  = df['Trade'].rank(ascending=False)
df['Trade Order2']  = df['Trade'].rank(ascending=True)
df['Max Ordered Number']  = df[['Volume Order', 'Trade Order']].max(axis=1)
df['Final Sorted Number'] = df[['Max Ordered Number', 'Trade Order2']].apply(tuple, axis=1).rank(ascending=False)
df.drop('Trade Order2', axis=1)
```

Output;

```
       Code  Volume  Trade  Value  Volume Order  Trade Order  Max Ordered Number  Final Sorted Number
0     ApplA     500   1000   <NA>             2            2                   2                    4
1    Amazon    1000    500   <NA>             1            4                   4                    2
2  Facebook     250    750   <NA>             3            3                   3                    3
  3   ApplE     100   1500   <NA>             4            1                   4                    1
```

I have 2 dataframes. There is no common column name. But there are common values. My first dataframe is located above. İts name is "df".

The other dataframe's name is "buffer".

| Name | Place |
| --- | --- |
| AppLA | U30 |
| Amazon | U30 |
| AppLA | U20 |
| Facebook | U10 |
| ApplE | U10 |
| Amazon | U20 |
| AppLA | U10 |
| Amazon | row |
| Facebook | U20 |
| Amazon | U10 |
| AppLE | U20 |

my purpose is to embed the "Buffer" dataframe into the dataframe named ""df". As you can see, there is no common column name. But there are common values. By opening 3 new columns in the dataframe named df, the dataframe named "Buffer" vlookup the values ​​of the "Place" column into those 3 new columns.

Columns name will be "PLACE U10" - "PLACE U20" - PLACE "U30"

My expected output;

```
       Code  Volume  Trade  Value  Volume Order  Trade Order  Max Ordered Number  Final Sorted Number   PLACE U10   PLACE U20   PLACE U30
0     ApplA     500   1000   <NA>             2            2                   2                    4        U10           U20        U30
1    Amazon    1000    500   <NA>             1            4                   4                    2        U10           U20        U30 
2  Facebook     250    750   <NA>             3            3                   3                    3        U10           U20
  3   ApplE     100   1500   <NA>             4            1                   4                    1       U10            U20        U30
```

as you see, facebook doesn't has "u30".

**Can you help me to embed dataframe named buffer into dataframe named df with common values ​​without common column name? If necessary, I can make the column names the same.**

Comment: In `buffer` there is `Place` with value `row` for `Amazon`.  Is it a typo?  Can we skip this row ?   Also, the spelling of some names are different `ApplA` and `AppLA`, are they the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot on dataframe `buffer` using [`.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), then use [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to join `df` with the pivoted table of `buffer`, aligning index of `Code` in `df` with index of `Name` in the pivoted table, as follows:

```
buffer_pivot = buffer.pivot(index='Name', columns='Place', values='Place').add_prefix('PLACE ')

df = df.set_index('Code').join(buffer_pivot).reset_index()
```

**Data Input**

```
print(buffer)

       Name Place
0     ApplA   U30
1    Amazon   U30
2     ApplA   U20
3  Facebook   U10
4     ApplE   U10
5    Amazon   U20
6     ApplA   U10
7  Facebook   U20
8    Amazon   U10
9     ApplE   U20
```

**Result:**

```
print(buffer_pivot)

Place    PLACE U10 PLACE U20 PLACE U30
Name                                  
Amazon         U10       U20       U30
ApplA          U10       U20       U30
ApplE          U10       U20       NaN
Facebook       U10       U20       NaN


print(df)


       Code  Volume  Trade  Volume Order  Trade Order  Max Ordered Number  Final Sorted Number PLACE U10 PLACE U20 PLACE U30
0     ApplA     500   1000           2.0          2.0                 2.0                  4.0       U10       U20       U30
1    Amazon    1000    500           1.0          4.0                 4.0                  2.0       U10       U20       U30
2  Facebook     250    750           3.0          3.0                 3.0                  3.0       U10       U20       NaN
3     ApplE     100   1500           4.0          1.0                 4.0                  1.0       U10       U20       NaN
```

Comment: this is awesome :) thnx

Comment: @Bianconera  Congrat you now got enough reputation to upvote.  You can now also upvote if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)).

Comment: @Bianconera  Seen you posted a question and got closed.  Probably, people think your question was too long.  Try break it up into small questions in the future.  Also don't write a lot of repeated words like `Can you help me about if conditions located below` to attract attention.  This would just give the opposite effect.  Take note.

Comment: thnx @SeaBean, I will do what you tell me.  As I told you, this query is really simple when you read

Comment: @Bianconera  I haven't read in detailed your new question yet.  Will read soon!  Remember to upvote my answer of this question if you like it.   :-)

Comment: I acc. your answer. It was really god. Please read my new query when you are free. I need really help:)

Comment: @Bianconera  Ok, will look at it shortly.  Just remind again to upvote my answer here if you find it helpful.  (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)).

Comment: @Bianconera  No longer can see your new question ?   Is it closed ?

Comment: someone vote to delete it :) I will post again shortly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69446064/if-statement-on-dataframe can you help me :) I seperate it.

Comment: Seen your new question.  It's still looks a very long and complicated question.  Found it's closed too.  Keep in mind people here don't like question like giving them a big project.  They don't want to take the burden of solving many steps to arrive at a solution.  Short questions with quick answers are most welcome and mostly answered quickly.  And bear in mind also that you are not sharing your project here.  This site is for you to ask short question when you meet problem during working on a small step of the total project.  Keep in mind, break onto small steps and small questions.